# Block SnackBar repeatedly

Tags: flutter

```
class SnacbarView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnacbarView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _showSnackBar() {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(
          'SnackBar de ejemplo',
          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1300),
      ));
    }

    return ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('ShowSnackBar'),
        onPressed: () {
          _showSnackBar();
        });
  }
}
```

I want that when I click the button twice in a row it does not request twice to show it, because this will wait for the first one to close and then open the second one. That is, if I click the button twice in a row and the snackbar is displayed, this request will be ignored.
Espero que me solucionen el problema. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: You can directly use https://pub.dev/packages/tap_debouncer

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach will be created a state variable for click event.

```dart
class SnacbarView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SnacbarView({super.key});

  @override
  State<SnacbarView> createState() => _SnacbarViewState();
}

class _SnacbarViewState extends State<SnacbarView> {
  bool isSnackBarActive = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _showSnackBar() {
      setState(() {
        isSnackBarActive = true;
      });
      const snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text(
          'SnackBar de ejemplo',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1300),
      );
      final scaffoldMessenger = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);

      scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(snackBar).closed.then((reason) {
        setState(() {
          isSnackBarActive = false;
        });
      });
    }

    return ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('ShowSnackBar'),
        onPressed: () {
          if (isSnackBarActive) return;

          _showSnackBar();
        });
  }
}
```